# What is the right git hook that I can define to check whether a file is updated?

Tags: git, hook

I have a github repo called my-service. To track my app, I'd like to use versions that I maintain in an `app.json`. I'd like this `app.json` file to be included every time I decide to merge into the `main` branch and the hook should validate this (i.e. fail merge when this file is not updated)

I've been looking into git-hooks and I've been considering git-commit and git-merge hooks. But I don't think `git-commit` would cut it because it'd be invoked in every commit which is not what I want. Is git `pre-merge` hook the right choice in what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how `app.json` relates to the reset of you code...
If you need `app.json` to by in sync with the rest of your code then `git-commit` is the proper once since you don't want to commit an invalid code.
If you use feature branches with pull/merge requests and `app.json` is independent of the rest of your code then maybe `git-push` should be considered.
I'm not clear how `git-merge` would work with pull/merge requests though...

Comment: essentially, when I merge to `main` that's a version update. And the merge SHOULD fail if there's no `version.json` included in the PR :)

Comment: then `git-merge` seems a way to go

Comment: @Saturnian if you find my answer useful pls upvote it (the arrow up). if my answer provides the solution pls accept it (the checkbox), thanks. that way i'll be motivated to answer you in the future